# How to configure WSO2 Api Manager to provide JWT as access token?

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, access-token, wso2-api-manager

Is there a way to provide JWT instead of what's by default, because I need to see the information about roles, permissions and other things inside it?

Comment: Do you want to pass it to your backend services? Then this should be helpful: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Passing+Enduser+Attributes+to+the+Backend+Using+JWT